# Mutate and then rerender a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with an event handler for a "like" icon.  I want to be able to click the like icon, update the database to record that the user has liked this item and then re-render the component to change the icon to reflect that the user has liked the item.  This is not working.  It seems that the rerender happens before the mutation so I cannot pick up the changes.  Here is the code:

```
handleFavourite = () => {
    const {
      post, 
      client: apolloClient,
      currUser,
      registerPromise
    } = this.props;
    var result;
    const postId = post._id;
    if (currUser.library.includes(post._id)) {
      console.log("changed to not liked")        
      result = removeFromLibrary({postId: postId}  , apolloClient);
    }else {
      console.log("changed to yes, liked!")
      result = addToLibrary( {postId: postId} , apolloClient);
    };
    this.setState(state => ({ liked: !currUser.library.includes(post._id) }));

    return result;
```

Here is the code in the render to set the icon to the appropriate state:

```
<CardActions className={classes.actions} disableActionSpacing>
  <IconButton
    className={classnames(classes.unliked, {
      [classes.liked]: currUser.library.includes(post._id),
    })}
    aria-label="Add to favorites"
    onClick={this.handleFavourite}
  >
    <FavoriteIcon />
```

Comment: Arent your `removeFromLibrary` and `addToLibrar` async?

Comment: @callback yes, they are async.  I am looking into that now, seeing that this will affect the order of things.  I am still confused.

Comment: The answer by Xuan-Hung Trinh should fix your issue! Also you probably dont have to return the result, since it's not used anywhere afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your removeFromLibrary & addToLibrary are async functions, you can just await for completion

```
handleFavourite = async () => {
    const {
      post, 
      client: apolloClient,
      currUser,
      registerPromise
    } = this.props;
    var result;
    const postId = post._id;
    if (currUser.library.includes(post._id)) {
      console.log("changed to not liked")        
      result = await removeFromLibrary({postId: postId}  , apolloClient);
    }else {
      console.log("changed to yes, liked!")
      result = await addToLibrary( {postId: postId} , apolloClient);
    };
    this.setState(state => ({ liked: !currUser.library.includes(post._id) }));

    return result;
```